# Redirection to external links fails on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, window.location

I am facing this strange issue only on safari.
In my webapp app, I redirect to some links using window.location.href
For all these links a connection lost error is returned from the browser on safari, working fine with chrome and firefox.
And when I retry the link a few times, it also starts to work on Safari.

So for example there is a button A, which onClick has window.location.href to "https://example.net", now when I click any links of this type, on first attempts it fails on safari, never ever occurred on Chrome or Firefox. Also if the whole page is still loading and I click, it works.
And everthing works in local enviroment, but doesn't work on stage and production.
Please help me out on this one, I have tried a lot of combinations like using anchor links tags instead of button, but button was used for a reason. Anyways If anyone has similar issues and know something about, please help me.

Comment: This sounds like the device is just having connectivity problems to the site you try to redirect to. Assigning to window.location just makes the browser open that page, there's nothing you can do differently in your code.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for answering. 
Every device has the same issue like if we open it on mac by using chrome, works.
by using safari, fails. The same goes for mobiles using the safari mobile browser.
Also checked on different safari versions.
And if the page is still loading, and I click it works every time. But if page it fully loaded, will fail on safari

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Assigning to `window.location.href` is no different from going to that URL by typing it into the address bar or following a link. Nothing in your JavaScript or server is involved.

Comment: for me it was webex extension, after uninstalling the extension. links started opening in safari